# How to disable Azure Devops email notifications for Pre-deployment Approval

Tags: azure-devops

We have a continuous delivery pipeline which has a pre-approval step for the prod deployment.  Many of the releases will only be deployed to lower environments before we pick a final release to move to production.   Despite disabling notifications, ADO is still sending out emails to approve prod deployment every time a release moves through all stages.

Is there a way to shut these off?  I don't want an approver inadvertently clicking on `approve` in an email and sending the release off to prod.

This is how the release notifications are configured in the project -- both manual intervention and approval pending are disabled:

[image]